# USB stick no longer recognized

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, android, tv

So this has happened to 2 USB sticks I own.

I have a Sony XBR-65X900F tv which takes a USB stick.  I loaded some videos onto the stick from my Windows 10 computer.

I then stuck the stick into the TV and left there for a few weeks, watched some videos and such.  Then I wanted to place more videos onto the stick and now the stick is not recognized by the Windows 10 machine, but the stick is still recognized by the TV.

I've tried the device manager on windows 10 (uninstalling and then restarting).  I've tried the diskpart but the drive doesn't show up.  The computer just doesn't recognize it.

I browsed the stick on the TV and there's the videos plus a few Android folders like VLC (I used VLC to watch the videos) and some Android centric folders which weren't there before.  It's almost like the tv formatted the stick for Android so the Windows 10 machine can't read it.

So my question is, how can I get the USB stick to work on Windows 10, hopefully not losing my videos?

**Update**: Pics of device manager

When the drive is first plugged in, it shows up.  But after 10 seconds, it goes away.  See second pic.

[image]

The drive then gets an error and disappears from the disk drives and goes to the USB controllers with an error.  I have the events tab open there.  I have tried uninstalling the USB controller, then rebooting, and then plugging it back in but it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? For example, show a screenshot of Disk Management?

Comment: I had this happen, with an LG TV.  It had somehow removed the drive letter. When I used Windows disk manager to assign a drive letter everything was hunky dory. Give it a try and let us know

Comment: Please kindly check if the methods posted in Microsoft official document can help you:[USB Device not recognized error when you try to access a USB external hard drive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/usb-device-not-recognized-error)

Comment: Make sure it is not an USB issue. Do not use extension cables or the front USB port. Use an USB port on the back side of your computer.

Comment: @Robert tried that.  Nothing.

Comment: @Mawg I can't assign a drive letter if I can't see it though.  It doesn't come up in the disk management.

Comment: @Tom nothing is being displayed there.  The stick doesn't show up.

Comment: @dev4life Can you check/show `Device Manager` and see what's under `Universal Serial Bus controllers` and `Disk drives` (and maybe also `Storage controllers`)?

Comment: @tomyan I have updated the original post with images.  Sorry for not getting back to your sooner.